# Knot theory program turning graphical input into PD / Gauss code or braid (Mac OS X)

Tags: math-software, computational-geometry, knot-theory

Are there any programs that run on OS X (and not just Windows) that can take a knot diagram as graphical input and convert it to a PD / Gauss code or braid? This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81137/graphical-entry-knot-theory-program-for-mac).

For comparison: On Windows, one can use LinKnot inside the Mathematica KnotTheory' package to convert a hand-drawn knot diagram into a Gauss code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SnapPy has a link editor that can give you the DT code: https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/plink.html